# Highchart drill down only display one data serie

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to implement a drill down on a bar chart.
My data series are splitted on 6 categories on the x axis and I have three different series (Social, Cognitive and Language).

I would like to be able to drill down in my series. For example, 'social' is made of 'Family' and 'Personnal'.

My problem is that highchart only wants to drill down into one data serie. In my case I would like the drill down to display serveral data series.

In the fiddle below, I would like the drill down from 'Social' to display the series 'Family' and 'Personnal'. But highchart only display the 'Personnal' serie.

Is there a standard way to do this with Highcharts?

```
    series: [
  {
    name: 'Social',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [
      { y: 10, drilldown: 'A' },
      { y: 5, drilldown: 'A' },
      { y: 3, drilldown: 'A' },
      { y: 1, drilldown: 'A' },
      { y: 0, drilldown: 'A' },
      { y: 0, drilldown: 'A' },
    ],
    color: '#EEAA3C',
  },
  {
    name: 'Cognitive',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [6, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    color: '#86BD4A',
  },
  {
    name: 'Language',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    color: '#E26E3E',
  },
],
   drilldown: {
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Family',
      id: 'A',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      color: '#F2B553',
    },
    {
      name: 'Personal',
      id: 'A',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [9, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0],
      color: '#F8CC87',
    },
  ],
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pacambi/3k4eng7w/

Thanks !

Comment: Hi @PA.Cambi, Check this thread: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=35350 about drilldown to multiple series and please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek thanks for the example! I think it fits what I'm trying to achieve. I was hoping to find a solution without the need to add a chart function, but I guess this is the only way to go.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to achieve drilldown from one series to multiple.